# Selecting fields and limiting total results in MongoDB query (Meteor)

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor app I am trying to receive a limited number of users (on the server!). Of those users I only want to receive a few specified fields.

Why does this query not work as expected?

```
const users = Meteor.users.find(
  {
    'roles.__global_roles__': {$in: ['myRole']},
    $and: query
  },
  {fields: {
    username: 1,
    firstName: 1,
    lastName: 1,
    update: 1
  }},
  {
    limit: 2,
    sort: {'update.any': -1}
  }
).fetch();
```

With this query, limit and sort are ignored. Only the selected fields are received.

I then tried this:

```
const users = Meteor.users.find(
  {
    'roles.__global_roles__': {$in: ['myRole']},
    $and: query
  },
  {
    limit: 2,
    sort: {'update.any': -1}
  }
).fetch();
```

Now limit and sort works but obviously I get the whole user object with all fields.

What is the solution to combining both?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find() has 2 parameters, you're providing 3 in your first example. try this:

```
const users = Meteor.users.find(
  {
    'roles.__global_roles__': {$in: ['myRole']},
    $and: query
  },
  {fields: {
    username: 1,
    firstName: 1,
    lastName: 1,
    update: 1
  },
    limit: 2,
    sort: {'update.any': -1}
  }
).fetch();
```

iow, fields, limit, and sort are all part of the same JSON object as the 2nd argument.

Comment: Damn! Thanks for helping me use my eyes.